# Bluemix dashDB couchDB(?) error

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

After an attempt to create a new dashDB instance, a distinctly non-Netezza/DB2 error is thrown when trying to "manage" this newly purchased instance.

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.executeRequest:-1' 

    org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Error executing request. 

    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDatabaseBase.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.repository.CloudantRepo.getProvisionedServiceInstance(CloudantRepo.java:382)
    at com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.controller.BluShiftHTTPController.getInstanceStatus(BluShiftHTTPController.java:870)
    at com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.controller.RestEndPoint.launchDashboard(RestEndPoint.java:513)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 --- clipped for your sanity ---
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at [internal classes]

    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

    ... 72 more
```

I'm not quite sure what CouchDB has to do with dashDB, but in any event, another day, another ungracefully handled.

I'll just try again tomorrow, that usually fixies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your description you got the error above when trying to launch the console to manage the dashDB instance you just created.

This confirms the exception you are seeing, specifically this line:

```
com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.controller.RestEndPoint.launchDashboard(RestEndPoint.java:513)
```

The dashDB console is a Web UI with a backend developed using Cloudant NoSQL DB, which is based off of Couch DB. Hence the Couch DB exception you are seeing.

The Cloudant NoSQL DB was probably offline at the moment you tried to launch it, but I agreed that the exception should be handled properly. I will create an internal defect to get the dashDB team provide a fix for this.